# Distributing .jar files

Tags: jar, distribution

I wanted to distribute a .jar file to a layman audience (all windows users). But I can't run the jar file myself unless I do it from cmd using `"java -jar "C:\..\file.jar"`.

When I double click on the file nothing happens (the default program is Java Platform SE Binary). Someone suggested [this site](http://windowstipoftheday.blogspot.com/2005/10/setting-jar-file-association.html) but I couldn't follow along in Win8.

So I want the user to be able to double click on the jar file and launch it directly without me telling them to open command prompt and typing stuff, or giving them the link.

PS: it is a very simple non-GUI application. Thanks for your time.

Comment: IF it's a non-GUI application, how is the user going to interact with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is to create a `file.bat` script that will run the jar, with this simple line in it:

```
java -jar file.jar
```

Give the users both files, `file.jar` and `file.bat`, and they can double-click on `file.bat` to run it.

In theory, if the jar file has a manifest in it (`META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`) with the main class defined in `Main-Class:` then it should be runnable by double-click. However, you say the app doesn't have a GUI, in which case it will run just fine, but you won't be able to see it.

In any case, the `bat` file should help, in the worst case users can just run that and not worry about typing `java -jar ...` etc.

Comment: I am not very familiar with batch files, but won't I need to write the full directory of the file in the command? In which case I won't be able to know since the user can put it anywhere.

Comment: In Windows, when you double-click on a `.bat` file, it will be executed from the directory it is in. So if the jar is in the same directory as the bat, then you don't need to specify absolute path. Try it!

Comment: oh, I see, so when I double click the jar file it runs but god knows where, but when I run it from cmd it runs in cmd. I just tried it again with GUI app, and it ran directly, no cmd. The batch file worked. Thanks man, I taught me a lot, appreciate it more than I can say.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to click on the check mark under the vote counter to mark as "accepted" answer ;-)

Comment: You got it. Just one more thing, Do they (the users) need JDK intalled or JRE or both?

Comment: JRE should be enough! ("JRE" is for runtime, "JDK" is for development. They won't be developing much will they ;-)

Comment: I figured, since the java.exe file being used lies in the jdk\bin folder they might need it. Again, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

How did you create the jar file? Jar files have a manifest file inside to, amount others, indicate the location of your main method. Check that this is correct.

You should be able to run the app by double clicking it but it can only be a program with a GUI or a program without direct user interaction.

Comment: I built the jar file using NetBeans, and the app works fine from command prompt. I also tried the same thing with GUI app and it doesn't open by double clicking.

Comment: I retried the GUI application and it worked directly. But the non-GUI works only from cmd. I figured it out. Thanks